# WPF and touch - focus issue

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, windows-8.1, .net-4.6

I have a `WPF` `.NET 4.6` application running on a `Windows 8.1` tablet and for the last few days I've been struggling to make my app `touch` friendly  to make it work as expected. My main problems are focus related, these affect several controls in my app. for example:

- Textboxes: sometimes requires a double or triple touch in order to get input focus, they do enter a mouse over state but the caret isn't there;
- ComboBoxes: takes a couple of touches in order to open it, and once touching an item in order to select it the combo stays open with the newly selected item highlighted;
  [image: combobox focus problem]
- Buttons: takes a couple of clicks to run the connected command and stay in mouse over state;
- Keyboard support

There are a couple of approaches I tried while searching for a solution that each has it's own downsides:

- Removing the tablet support for the entire application ([taken from here](http://brianlagunas.com/showing-windows-8-touch-keyboard-wpf/)). this one solves most of the focus problems mentioned above but makes scrolling (and I guess some other Tablet related functionality that I haven't found yet) unusable.
- Explicitly activating the keyboard when required ([Example here](http://mheironimus.blogspot.co.il/2015/05/adding-touch-keyboard-support-to-wpf.html)). Focus problem remains, scrolling works as expected
- I also tried to remove all styles and tested everything on 2 different tablets from different manufacturers but without success

Recently [Microsoft announced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/07/20/announcing-net-framework-4-6.aspx) that "Touch is better" But I couldn't find any official documentation about the best way to approach this subject.

Any suggestion on how to make my application work better with touch would be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove mouse over state by using following behavior:

```
public class TouchDeviceMouseOverUIElementFixBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.StylusUp += AssociatedObject_StylusUp;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.StylusUp -= AssociatedObject_StylusUp;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_StylusUp(object sender, StylusEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (control != null)
        {
            if (!VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(control, "Normal", true))
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, "Normal", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use this code? connect to controls touch event?